Create list of purchased items grouped by a parameter
So I would like to create list of products that purchased by the customers as described below.
On the first table, I have a list of Purchased Order like this.

On the different sheet, I would like to make a summary of items purchased by customer A, B, C, D, F, H into a single cell for each customer, like this:

On Sheet2, I use =UNIQUE filter to get list of unique customer from Sheet1. So what formula should I use on B2 to get output like that? I've tried out some textjoin or concatenate formula with =vlookup function, but it didn't works.


You may try this in Cell_B2 of Sheet2:
=join(", ";filter(Sheet1!B:B;Sheet1!A:A=A2))


Hi, thank you so much for the formula. This solve my case, simpler than I thought.
But in my case, I put $ too. So I did use this combination:
=join(", ";filter(Sheet1!$B:$B;Sheet1!$A:$A=A2))

You may try the following dynamic array formula-
=LET(x,UNIQUE(TOCOL(Sheet1!A2:A,1)),
y,MAP(x,LAMBDA(t,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(Sheet1!B2:B,Sheet1!A2:A=t)))),
HSTACK(x,y))

Little bit simpler-
=LET(x,UNIQUE(TOCOL(Sheet1!A2:A,1)),HSTACK(x,MAP(x,LAMBDA(t,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(Sheet1!B2:B,Sheet1!A2:A=t))))))


